# Explain the error in my android application

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app,but can't launch it due to following error.Can anybody tell about this error?

```
05-04 00:52:31.682 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-04 00:52:31.865 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rsa_solutions.attendance-2/lib/x86_64
05-04 00:52:37.187 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rsa_solutions.attendance-2/lib/x86_64
05-04 00:52:37.285 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-04 00:52:37.285 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.rsa_solutions.attendance, PID: 2420
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rsa_solutions.attendance/com.rsa_solutions.attendance.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:145)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:186)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:170)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:502)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
                                                                                at com.rsa_solutions.attendance.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
05-04 00:52:40.839 2420-2420/com.rsa_solutions.attendance I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2420 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's in your MainActivity.java - line number :20

Comment: please share your code

Comment: My MainActivity.java is Main Activity in my android application. @ReazMurshed

Comment: Sorry MainActivity.java is the java class of  My MainActivity of my android applicaion @ReazMurshed